# Nested resource parameters not being set properly in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, controllers

I'm getting a curious error after submitting my form. Been trying to solve this for several hours..

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"items", :item_id=>"141", :matter_id=>"3"} missing required keys: [:id]`

The parameters are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"w0D7XmX2X2/ZMU19T6RlMvWCEClXnCFFOR+4EdIFvWg=",
"comment_item"=>{"item_id"=>"",
"name"=>"kaljdf",
"body"=>"yet another comment test"},
"commit"=>"Post Comment",
"matter_id"=>"3",
"item_id"=>"141"}
```

**I have the following models:**

```
class Matter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has many :discoveries
  delegate :items, to: :discoveries
end

class Discovery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :matter
  scope :items, -> { where(type: 'Item') }
end

class Item < Discovery
  has_many :comment_items
end

class CommentItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

**Controllers:**

```
class ItemsController < DiscoveriesController
  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @comment_item = CommentItem.new
  end

  def edit
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end
end

class CommentItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @comment_item = @item.comment_item.new
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @comment_item = @item.comment_items.new(comment_item_params)
    if @comment_item.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Comment was successfully created'
      redirect_to matter_item_url(matter_id: params[:matter_id])
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Error creating comment: #{@comment.errors}"
      redirect_to matter_item_url(@matter, @item)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment_item = CommentItem.find(params[:id])
    @comment_item.destroy
    redirect_to(@comment_item.item)
  end

  private
    def set_comment_item
      @comment_item = CommentItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    def comment_item_params
      params.require(:comment_item).permit(:name, :body, :item_id, :matter_id)
    end
end
```

**The show action for the item resource:**

```
<p>
  <strong>Matter:</strong>
  <%= @item.matter_id %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Content:</strong>
  <%= @item.content %>
</p>
<hr /> 
<%= form_for @comment_item, url: matter_item_comment_items_path(matter_id: @item.matter, item_id: @item.id) do |f| %> 
  <% if @comment_item.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
      <% @comment_item.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %> 
  <%= f.hidden_field :item_id %> 

  <p> 
    <%= f.label :name %><br /> 
    <%= f.text_field :name %> 
  </p> 

  <p> 
    <%= f.label :body %><br /> 
    <%= f.text_area :body %> 
  </p> 

  <p> 
    <%= f.submit "Post Comment" %> 
  </p> 
<% end %> 
<%= render :partial => 'comment_item', :collection => @item.comment_items %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_matter_item_path(id: @item.id) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', matter_items_path %>
```

**Routes**

```
resources :items do
  resources :comment_items
end

resources :matters do
  resources :items do
    resources :comment_items
  end
end
```

When looking at CommentItems in the console, I see that the comments are in fact being added to the model with their correct ID's, but they don't seem to be passed as parameters.. What am I missing?

I've reviewed [Rails 4 form_for double nested comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154379/rails-4-form-for-double-nested-comments) and [Rails 3.2 - Nested Resource Passing ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609040/rails-3-2-nested-resource-passing-id) but I didn't have much luck..

I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: your request is going to ItemsController instead of CommentItemsController

Comment: Thank you! Where do you see that?

Answer (score 0):

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"items", :item_id=>"141", :matter_id=>"3"} missing required keys: [:id]`

your request is going to ItemsController instead of CommentItemsController

see :controller => "items"